# Dialogflow Prameter in Url

Tags: parameters, nestjs, parameter-passing, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

can someone help please???, so i just want to pass parameters in dialogflow url webhook, but i didn't know how??`//here is the url
[https://ef9c-41-141-192-237.ngrok.io/email/sendemail?toemail=$email&subject=$subject&text=$msg'](https://ef9c-41-141-192-237.ngrok.io/email/sendemail?toemail=$email&subject=$subject&text=$msg%27)
$msg $email $subject are the parametrs , but the apps can not read the params [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuP2M.png)

here is my intent with params

Comment: please smeone answer mee???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Posting a comment asking for an answer just a minute after you ask the question is unreasonable. Please be courteous of other people's time as well. The more you can provide to make your question as clear as possible to others, the better your chances are of getting a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how the Dialogflow URL webhook works.

The end point of the webhook URL is expected to be able to handle a POST in the [Dialogflow JSON Request format](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_request) and to reply using the response format. Your handler can get the parameters from that request object and then call the endpoint using the parameter format that you expect.